# Using em without a need to apply division

Tags: css, sass

This is the rule I had when using `rem`:

```
.title-main {
  font-size: 14rem;
  letter-spacing: 9rem;
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
  margin-right: -9rem;
}
```

Since I need the scaling capability, I am switching this component to `em`:

```
.title-main {
  font-size: 14em;
  letter-spacing: calc(9em/14);
  margin-bottom: calc(8em/14);
  margin-right: -calc(9em/14);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way, whereby I would still be able to specify the non-font-size properties in integer numbers?

Comment: If any details are missing or something is not clear in the question, I will very much appreciate a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the main problem is that you hard-code the font-size value (14 in your example). If you use SASS, I would write the code as the following:

```
$fontSize: 14;

.title-main {
  font-size: #{$fontSize} + 'em';
  letter-spacing: calc(9em/#{$fontSize});
  margin-bottom: calc(8em/#{$fontSize});
  margin-right: -calc(9em/#{$fontSize});
}
```

That outputs exactly your code but in a more efficient way; hope that's what you meant.

In my example I've put the variable outside the declaration (that's the best scenario), but it can be inside the declaration as well.